# How to setup Ahoy.user_method for different models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ahoy

I'm new to Ruby on Rails, using Ahoy to track visits and events in my app.  I have 2 different devise models, how do I set up `Ahoy.user_method` to each one?

My devise models are `PlayerLog` and `CoachLog`. Should I set this up like this:

```
Ahoy.user_method = :true_current_player_log
Ahoy.user_method = :true_current_coach_log
```

Thanks! Regards, Gustavo

Comment: Edit Question:
I'm new with RoR and new using Ahoy to track visits and events at my app.

Ahoy.user_method is a setting up for Ahoy (not Ahoy_Email). Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing more about your specific use case (such as when a user is a player vs a coach), you can set the `user_method` to a lambda and handle the logic there:

```
Ahoy.user_method = -> do |controller|
  if player_user?
    true_current_player_log
  else
    true_current_coach_log
  end
end
```